# Sharing Firebase authentication session from iOS container app with app extensions

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to post to my database using the Share application extension in iOS. Is there any way I can use the same authentication sessions used by the container app? My database rules are currently set up to only allow authenticated users to read/write. This is fine for the container app, as the authentication occurs there and a session is set up. However I want to be able to add to the database from the Share sheet in iOS, and Apple does not allow to change much information between the container app and the app extension. I can store some benign data in group UserDefaults, but I would not like to store any sensitive information there (like user login details). I've been looking for a way to do this without leaving my database open to the outside world. I would welcome any suggestions or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understand your problem correctly, but you can use shared Keychain instead of UserDefaults using AppGroups

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps?language=objc[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps?language=objc)